# How to use JMeter for Login Authentication through Identity server 5.2 for ASP.Net MVC Web Application

Tags: authentication, logging, jmeter, asp.net-identity

I am trying to do the performance test for the ASP.Net MVC Web Application,
the Application is working with the Identity Server 5.2 to Login authentication. 
I'm facing problem with login through the identity server.

Jmeter Version: 5.1.1

**Description of the case:**

- Open URL of the website.
- It will redirect you to the Identity website
- Fill username and password
- Log in to the application
- Final URL will be the same as in point 1.

I was following the instruction below,
https://[www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=hGkrSFKcj10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=hGkrSFKcj10) 
base on this I created a Jmeter test plan

- Test Plan
- Thread Group
- First HTTP Req - GET the "https://CorrectURL.com/

  - Assertion
  - View result three
- Second HTTP Req - Post the username and Password on the https://identity.com/core/identityTokenUniqueForEverySingleLogin

  - Assertion
  - View result three

**First HTTP request was successful:**

**I received Sampler Results:**

- HTTP Request - GET the Identity-0  **Response code: 301**
- HTTP Request - GET the Identity-1  **Response code: 302**
- HTTP Request - GET the Identity-2  **Response code: 302**
- HTTP Request - GET the Identity-3  **Response code: 302**
- HTTP Request - GET the Identity-4  **Response code: 200**

**Second response:**

Because every time Identity token is different, I don't know how can I take the token and use it during login.

Also what kind of information do I need to do the HTTP POST?

Can I Find then somewhere in Development tool?

**I used also BlazeMeter to record the login process but when I'm running it again I'm receiving:**

- Response code: 405 Method Not Allowed
- Response code: 500  Internal Server Error

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Identity Server documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html#sign-in) it appears to be using a [cookie](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html#cookie-authentication) therefore my expectation is that adding a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) should solve the problem (at least partially).

Not knowing the details of your Identity Server configuration details and seeing request/response sequence it is hard to come up with the comprehensive instructions, however my expectation is that it is the matter of simple [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) to wit:

1. Open your application login page (make sure that HTTP Cookie Manager is there)
2. Open identity server
3. Extract the token from the response if needed using a suitable [JMeter PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save the value into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
4. Use the JMeter Variable from the step 3 instead of recorded hard-coded token